# TextView inside a ListView: setTextHighlightColor() issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, textview

I have `ListView` and `TextView` inside it. Now the thing is: I want to change the `TextColor` over the cell's selection in the `ListView`, but setting `setTextHighlightColor` of `TextView` isn't giving this output.

I have tried setting a selector for this, but that is not helping too.

Can this be solved? What might be causing the issue to populate?

> The code layout is:

**Cell.xml**

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail" 
    android:layout_width="48dip"
    android:layout_height="48dip" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" 
/>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/username" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="top" 
    android:text="Username" 
    android:textColor="@drawable/timeline_username_selector"
/>
<TextView 
    android::id="@+id/time" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
    android:text="31stMarch,2010" 
    android:textColor="@drawable/timeline_username_selector"
/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textTweet" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/username"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="top" 
    android:textColor="@drawable/timeline_tweet_selector"
/>
```

The Selector is a simple one

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your layout.xml, it will help.

Comment: I have posted the Cell.xml and the Layout is simple one containing the ListView inside a LinearLayout and this activity is placed inside a Tab Activity for launching the Activity from Tab Widget.

Comment: What is going wrong is really very unknown

Comment: is the problem that the textcolor on the textview in not the color you prefer when you select a item/row in the listview?   Cell.xml is the layout for a row/item in the listview ?

Comment: the text color is changing but the thing is that on touching the Textview my background selector behaves differently

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827416/how-to-define-colorstatelist-for-textview

Answer (score 0):

As you know, you'll need a state drawable to show different colors for different states:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#ff0000" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ff0000" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ff0000" />
    <item android:color="#000000" />
</selector>
```

Make sure to pass the selected state from the main row view down to child views in the row:

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```