# How to define ColorStateList for TextView?

Tags: android, listview, colors, listviewitem

When my `ListViewItem` is highlighted, I want the text to turn white. How can I define this?

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/testcolor1"/>
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/testcolor2" />
   <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/testcolor3" />
   <item android:color="@color/testcolor5"/>
 </selector>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: Why did you posted the code? What it shows? (how do you use the drawable?)

Comment: Well I'm not sure how to change the textcolor. I assumed it would be in the selector code, but it's probably not. So I'm hoping someone can answer the question because I don't know.

Answer (score 69):

Create file res/drawable/text_color.xml:

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <item android:color="#000000" />
</selector>
```

Then use `@drawable/text_color` from xml (or `R.drawable.text_color` from code) as text color for your list view items.

Comment: Thanks! can you show me an example of what a @drawable/text_color might look like?

Comment: Somewhat like android:textColor="@drawable/text_color" on a TextView.

Comment: that should go in res/color

Comment: yes, and be referred to as @color/text_color. A @color can point to either a color or a ColorStateList.

Comment: If you set the text colour programmatically, call Context.getResources().getColorStateList(R.drawable.text_color) to get a ColorStateList, and pass that into the EditText.setTextColor method that takes a ColorStateList.  Don't just pass the resource id in as an int (like I did...duh!).

Comment: @KonstantinBurov How to define custom state attributes instead of frameworks's `android:state_*`?

Answer (score 8):

Try this...

First, create a color state list `text_color.xml` placed in `res/color` directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">
  <item android:color="#000000" android:state_enabled="false"/>
  <item android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
</selector>
```

Second, use

```
getColorStateList(@NonNull Context context,
            @ColorRes int id)
```

method to get color state list.

```
textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, R.color.text_color))
```

Third, enable(true) or disable(false) based on your requirements,

```
textView.isEnabled = true //when item is highlighted
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what others have stated above, I would like to highlight one point, taken from the below url.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html

Note: The list of state specs will be matched against in the order that they appear in the XML file. For this reason, more-specific items should be placed earlier in the file. An item with no state spec is considered to match any set of states and is generally useful as a final item to be used as a default.

It's important that you have the broader condition towards the bottom in the selector tag.