# How to set TextColor using setTextColor(ColorsStateList colors)?

Tags: android, textcolor

I need to change text color when state change(pressed, focus)...

How to set the text color of a `TextView` using `ColorsStateList`?

Comment: Did you read this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506319/android-linearlayout-with-color-resource-what-am-i-doing-wrong

Comment: Your question is ambiguous- are you simply looking for a tutorial on the use of ColorStateList? Have you searched around at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827416/how-to-define-colorstatelist-for-textview

Comment: Yes, but i cant use XML. I need do this programatically

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If you need to set the colors in code (using ColorStateList), but still want to keep the color states in an XML, you might want to use this:

```
try {
    XmlResourceParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.color.your_colors);
    ColorStateList colors = ColorStateList.createFromXml(getResources(), parser);
    mText.setTextColor(colors);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle exceptions
}
```

res/color/your_colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#222222"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:color="#222222"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#222222"/>
    <item android:color="#0000ff"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: There is a much simpler way to achieve this: `mText.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.your_colors));`

Comment: @ol_v_er it doesn't seem to retain the color states if you set it that way (at least it wasn't for me). I had to use the method above in order to retain the selected color state, etc.

Comment: When does it doesn't retain the color states? When an configuration change occurs?

Comment: Ol_v_er's method (in the first comment, not in the answer) worked perfectly for me, all the states are retained (Android 2.3 & 4.4).

Comment: Just to update this for 2017, the better way would now be:

    mText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getContext(), R.color.my_color_statelist);

Answer (score 28):

You have to use [getColorStateList()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColorStateList(int))

I was also struggling with this problem, if you want to use a `state list`, you need to declared it in the `color` resources folder, instead of the `drawable` folder, and use the `setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.your_colors))`.

Comment: This was the solution for me. Android Studio 2.3 was showing very inconsistent behaviour with the selector in the 'drawable' folder. Sometimes it would work, sometimes it would get confused and just colour all the text pink. By adding a 'color' resource folder and putting the selector XML file in there, everything came good.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use ContextCompat to load a color state list

```
ColorStateList colors = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this,R.color.my_color_list);
```